# use .htaccess to deal with requests for backend and frontend

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yii

First of all, I apologize for any mistake in English

well, my question is this:

I have a folder that has the **backend**, and receives requests in the following path

*[root]/backend/www*`(which contains an index.php file that handles requests)`

I have a folder that has the **frontend**, and receives requests in the following path

*[root]/frontend/www*`(which contains an index.php file that handles requests)`

I have also a folder named **common** that is shared between the backend and frontend (contains the libraries of the framework, among other files)

> what in need, is when the access to this location:
>
> `h**p://localhost/andre/admin`
>
> rewrite it to:
>
> `h**p://localhost/andre/backend/www`  (how it currently is)

---

> In other words, instead of accessing the backend by:
>
> `h**p://localhost/andre/backend/www`
>
> use this address:
>
> `h**p://localhost/andre/admin`

---

> all other requests that do not point to:
>
> `h**p://localhost/andre/admin`
>
> be accessed by:
>
> `h**p://localhost/andre/ (ie, point to
>   h**p://localhost/andre/frontend/www)`

(I hope you can understand what I want)

I need help, on a way to do this with **.htaccess** file, I can not use Symlinks or Subdomains for this problem...

I've searched a lot in Google and here, but found nothing that worked or who could help me.

PS: I am using Yii Framework with YiiBoilerplate, but I think the solution should not be out there

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /andre/

RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ backend/www/index.php/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ frontend/www/index.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your **`/andre/.htaccess` file**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /andre/

RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ backend/www$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(frontend|backend)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/www/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: it works, but if the request is link like this:
`http://localhost/andre/admin/site/contact`
`http://localhost/andre/admin/user`
it always loads the admin homepage (http://localhost/andre/site/index )

Comment: What is location of above .htaccess? Is there any .htaccess in `/andre/admin/` also?

Comment: But if backend URL is rewritten to `/andre/backend/www` then this `/admin/.htaccess` won't be used at all.

Comment: **admin** its a virtual folder.

the above .htaccess file is in `/andre/backend/www`. And the code you provided, I pasted it in `/andre/.htaccess`

Comment: Then What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: the PASTBIN link refers to `/andre/backend/www/.htaccess` file

Comment: I understand that part but make sure my suggested rules are placed in `/andres/.htaccess` and if there are any more rules there then post them.

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted to know in which folder did you create it?

Comment: in document root (the **andre** folder)

Comment: Well your DocumentRoot is parent directory of andre I believe since you're entering `http://localhost/andre/admin/site/contact` in browser. With above .htaccess it is internally rewriting to `http://localhost/andre/backend/www/site/contact` when I test it.

Comment: yes, it was supposed to work, but the truth is that always rewrites for http://localhost/andre/backend/www/site/index

Comment: Which could be due to those additional rules in `/andre/backend/www/.htaccess`. For your testing you can have rule as this: `RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)?$ backend/www$1 [NC,L,R]` and see what URL you get in the browser.

Comment: i tested this URL: `http://localhost/andre/admin/site/contact` and redirects (but doesn't rewrite) to this URL: `http://localhost/andre/backend/www/site/contact`

Comment: Which is exactly same URL was I mentioned in my previous comment. So you can see the rule is behaving fine.

Comment: yes...
do you have any experience with Yii Framework?
the problem should be from there...

Comment: No I haven't used Yii so yes I suspect it could be due to Yii rules in  `/andre/backend/www/.htaccess`

Comment: `# @link http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config#apache
RewriteEngine on

# prevent httpd from serving dotfiles (.htaccess, .svn, .git, etc.)
RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php`

Comment: yes, for accept my awser i have to wait 3hours, but you edited your answer, i have accepted.